# How to disable closure of the main form in Borland C++

Tags: c++builder, vcl

```
When closing an application on close button (FormClose handler is called), 
there is a dialog if user is sure that he wants to close the application. 
If the result of the dialog is mrCancel, then I try to set the ModalResult
of a main form to mrNone like I do with other forms, but even though, the 
application still closes.

What is the solution?

Cheers.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the form's `FormCloseQuery`, set `CanClose` to false.